# É correto utilizar as duas formas seguintes num texto: endereço eletrónico e email?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, uso-de-palavras, significado-em-contexto

É correto utilizar as duas formas seguintes num texto: endereço eletrónico e email?

Provavelmente tem diferenças numa situação mais formal. Existem diferenças no Brasil e em Portugal para esta questão?

Comment: seria errado usar as duas expressões numa mesma frase pois uma é tradução da outra mas é correto usar uma ou outra na mesma frase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, ambos têm o mesmo significado.

No Brasil quase só se usa "e-mail" (por vezes "endereço de e-mail"), mas "correio eletrônico" é compreendido e pode ser considerado uma alternativa particularmente formal.

Vale dizer que "email" (i.e., sem hífen), embora muito frequente, [deve ser evitado](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/e-mail-ou-email/) em contextos formais.

Em Portugal, usa-se também "e-mail", mas "correio eletrónico" [pode ser](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/mail-e-mail-e-correio-eletronico/32574) (ou pelo menos já foi) considerado mais apropriado em contextos formais.

Comment: «mas [em Portugal] "correio eletrónico" pode ser considerado mais apropriado em contextos formais» Já foi, mas não acho que continue a ser... de qualquer forma, não está errado usar a expressão longa, e ninguém estranharia.

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil modifiquei a resposta para refletir tua informação.

Comment: Não é "imeu"? [humor]

Answer (score 0):

E-MAIL é um diminutivo do termo inglês "Eletronic Mail" que, em português é "Endereço Eletrônico". Os dois estão corretos e "endereço eletrônico" foi um termo muito utilizado no início, mas aos poucos foi sendo descartado do vocabulário português pela linguagem universal.